# Destructor called before end of scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The following program chrashes. But I don't really understand why. The boolean my_shared_resouce is in real life an asynchonous queue that eventually stops the loop inside of the thread via message passing.
However, the following program crashes because the destructor seems to be called multiple times. And the first time it does is long before the sleep in the main() finishes. If i remove the `delete my_shared_resource;` I can see the destructor is called three times...
However, following my current understanding the destructor should only be called when `main()` finishes.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ThreadedClass {

    public:

        ThreadedClass() {
            my_shared_resource = new bool(true);
        }

        virtual ~ThreadedClass() {
            delete my_shared_resource;
            cout << "destructor" << endl;
        }


        void operator()(){
            loop();
        }

        void stop() {
            *my_shared_resource = false;
        }

    private:

        void loop() {
            while (*my_shared_resource) {
                // do some work
                this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            }
        }

        bool* my_shared_resource;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ThreadedClass instance;
    std::thread t(instance);
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "Did some work in main thread." << endl;
    instance.stop();
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

compiled as g++ --std=c++0x thread.cpp -pthread

Would someone please enlighten me what is wrong about this design.

Comment: You have a data race, btw. Use a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ThreadedClass` gets copied both copies point to the same `my_shared_resource`, and both will delete it.

Use a `std::shared_ptr<bool>` instead:

```
class ThreadedClass {
public:
    ThreadedClass() : shared_resource(new bool(true)) { } 
    virtual ~ThreadedClass() { }
    void operator()() { loop(); }
    void stop() { *shared_resource = false; }

private:
    void loop() {
        while (*shared_resource) {
            // Do some work.
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<bool> shared_resource;
};
```

Comment: Oh, it gets copied, doooo.. That fully explains it. And I believe i can give shared_pointer a custom free function right, because in my bigger program I clearly make the same mistake. But there a GAsycQueue* is destroyed with g_async_queue_unref() and these are C Structs and functions

Comment: @hetepeperfan Yes, you can give `shared_ptr` a custom deleter function.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread
you are calling:

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

which

*Creates new std::thread object and associates it with a thread of execution. First the constructor copies/moves all arguments (both the function object f and all args...) to thread-accessible storage*

Thus your `my_shared_resourse` pointer gets copied and shared between several copies of the thread object and gets destroyed in several places. Either define the appropriate copy constructor/assignment operator or use shared pointers.